# Boolean Simplification Methods. : Karnaugh Maps vs Boolean Algebra

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I am practicing problems on **simplifying Boolean Expressions** with **Boolean Algebra** and **Karnaugh Maps**.

- I tried to simplify the same Boolean Expression using **both** ways
  but I got two different answers. Can that happen?
- After any Boolean Expression simplification, whatever may be the method, the answers should be same, right? Or can the answers be different?

I tried simplifying the expression
$$\mathcal{A'B'C'+A'B'C+A'BC'+ABC'+ABC}$$
With boolean algebra I got $\mathcal{A'B'C+AB}$, and with Karnaugh Maps I got $\mathcal{A'+B}$

Comment: How many variables were present?

Comment: 3 variables. ABC only

Comment: It might help if you gave a specific example here.  What was the expression you attempted to simplify, and what were the results?

Comment: A'B'C'+A'B'C+A'BC'+ABC'+ABC

Comment: Kmap result was A'+B

Comment: Boolean Algebra result was A'B'C+AB

Comment: The best way to check if these are the same is to write a truth table and check if the values are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Both **Karnaugh Map** and **Boolean Algebra Simplification** need not to give same answer. The answer may differ.

> The **Boolean Algebra Simplification** is sometimes **tricky** because
> we need smart use of **Properties** ***(Absorption and
> Distributive)*** and **Theorems** ***(Redundancy Theorem)***
>
> Even **K-Map Solutions are not unique.** The answer may differ based
> on your choice of pairing. The same set of minterms can be simplified in two ways as shown in this attached image.
> [image: Different Answer for K-Map]

Now, considering your problem, all the **three expressions are not equivalent**.

Let three expressions be
$\mathcal{F=A′B′C′+A′B′C+A′BC′+ABC′+ABC}$
$\mathcal{K=A′B′C+AB}$
$\mathcal{S=A′+B}$

| $\mathcal{A}$ | $\mathcal{B}$ | $\mathcal{C}$ | $\mathcal{F}$ | $\mathcal{K}$ | $\mathcal{S}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Clearly, $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathcal{K}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ aren't equivalent.

Thus, the claimed simplified expression (using K-Map and Boolean) are actually incorrect.

**The actual simplified expressions are :**

> $\mathcal{AB+A′B′+A′C′}$

> $\mathcal{AB+A′B′+BC′}$

Answer (score 0):

Boolean algebra and Karnaugh map simplification should give the same or very similar answers, though without some creativity the boolean algebra one may end up not getting quite as simple an answer because things that can be used to simplify some parts may have been absorbed by other parts.

Some expressions have multiple simplified forms that are equivalent!  In the specific case of $A'B'C' + A'B'C + A'BC'+ABC' + ABC$, there are two equivalent fully simplified forms:

- $AB + A'B' + A'C'$
- $AB + A'B' + BC'$

and a small variety of slightly less simplified forms (note the additional symbol on the last term):

- $AB + A'B' + A'BC$
- $AB + A'C' + A'B'C$
- $A'B' + BC' + ABC$

Unfortunately, neither of your two proposed solutions shown in the comments are correct, as can be seen by simply counting 'on' bits: $A'+B$ has $6$ on bits, and $A'B'C+AB$ has $3$, where the original has $5$.  I'm not sure how you got either of those, unfortunately: I can't find a place in my own workings where an error would create these.

Comment: thank you so much